# Per vertex mesh deformation

Tags: opengl, graphics, computer-vision, gpu

I am doing a project where i want to have i vertex buffer (in opengl) where I have vertices that make out a mesh of an image. Meaning that each pixel of the image consists of two triangles (a square pixel). I think I have achieved that by simple initializing a window with the size of the image and then having a vbo with a vertex grid also of the image size (grid of width and height).

For this image i also have a disparity/correspondence map(vector field) which a want to interpolate and use to deform this image mesh (deform the image/vertex grid). The idea comes from this article http://graphics.tu-bs.de/media/publications/stich08VTI.pdf (section 5) which is essentially what i want to do.

I want to have an image represented with a mesh and deform it by a vector field to have a new virtual view. How can this easily be done? I can't fully grasp how i am suppose to move the vertices in the vertex shader.

Firstly, it is pixel correspondence (in the vector field) but i can only move the vertices and one vertex belongs to two pixels so how do i deal with this (moving pixels)?

Secondly, is the phrase "per vertex mesh deformation" just moving the vertices in the vertex shader by some coordinates (in this case the vector field)?

And thirdly, if I manage to deform the mesh, how do I sample the original image correctly to get the "new view"? Do I just deform a set of UV coordinates by the same vector field as the image mesh and then sample the original image as a texture in the fragment shader?

Comment: In my opinion, this question is too broad. It's not a programming question, but more a conceptual one.

Comment: I dont see how to make it anymore specific? Maybe the second question on what the phrase actual is is broad, but how you transform pixels represented as a mesh in this specific way, how can that not be a specific programming question? (and the same for sampling for that matter). This method is mentioned in more than one  paper in this field so for someone who knows how to deform an image in this way i can't see how this is not a programming question. And even if you look at it in a conceptual way it is still very specific; how do a move pixels when they are reprensented as vertices?

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I'm looking for any articles to read up...